# jsplumb: How to create new element by dragging connector

Tags: javascript, jsplumb

I have been customizing the jsplumb flowchart example.  Currently, I can drag and create connectors between elements but I would like to now drag an element to a blank part of the screen (i.e. not an element) and catch that event.  Does anyone know which one that would be?

Comment: sorry unclear, you want to drag an element, which is not an element ?

Comment: Sorry... So let's say I have 2 elements, I can drag a connector to connect both of them.  But I'd also like to say, if I drag a new connecter from an element and it doesn't match up to another element... I'd like to dynamically create one.

Comment: there are many ways I can think of on how to to do this. You start with 2 sources & 2 targets and then on every new connection being established (`connection` event), create a new element pair/source/target as required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using jsPlumb.draggable, use jQuery draggable

```
$(".element").draggable({
                helper: 'clone',
                // appendTo: 'body',
                start: function(event, ui) {}, // console.log(event);console.log(ui)},
                stop: function(event, ui) {}, // console.log(event);//console.log(ui)},
                revert: 'invalid',
                cursor:'move',
                opacity: 0.5,
            });
```

API Docs - http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/

`start` & `stop` are the events fired when the drag starts and stops respectively.